# Best Case and Worst Case input for isPrime

Tags: python, big-o

```
def isPrime(num):
     for factor in range(2, num):
          if num % factor == 0:
                  return False
     return True
```

For the function, describe an input that would result in best-case
efficiency, then describe an input that would result in worst-case efficiency. This
generic input must work at any possible size; don't answer 1 for isPrime, for example.

I'm stuck here. I know we have to calculate best case and worst case for a given size of an input, but in an integer, what is the size? Is the answer `num = 3` for best case and `num>3` is prime for th worst case, or is it `num = infinity` for worse case? Pls help im stuck

Comment: Worst case is any prime number, bet case is any multiple of 2

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worst case is `O(n)` where `n` is the input number to check for prime (`num` in this case) and `n` is prime number. The best case is `O(1)` where `num` is divisible by 2